# simple fullscreen css slider

Tags: css, slider, fullscreen

I'm trying to make a very simple fullscreen css slider.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sy4hz/

This is normally how I'd do a really simple one, I don't think I'll ever have more then five things I want on it.  I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to make it fullscreen.  With a fixed width you can just tell it the photo size adn say move that many pixels over, I was thinking about doing it with percents, and just having the containing div be 100% height adn if it's 4 images slide it by percents, 25,75, 100 %.  The problem is if an image is wider then it is tall it would go off screen with this idea.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) ;) It's great, and very customisable.

Comment: hmmm, this is a possibility.  I think what I'm trying to do isn't actually all that complicated though, and I'd love to have someone explain a variation of what I'm trying.  It's a small slider, I'd rather not have to bring in a JS library if I didn't have to.

Comment: Using jQuery along with Supersized will take about 100KB, which isn't that much novadays. Also, if you want to solve your issue purely with CSS, be prepared for problems with older browsers.